# What alternatives are there to ipset for blocking large sets of ip addresses / address ranges?

Tags: ipset

Are there alternatives to ipset that offer similar efficiency in handling large sets of ip addresses or ip address ranges?

We originally used iptables to selectively block access to our servers for security- and spam-related reasons.

As the list of blocked ip addresses and ip address ranges grew, we migrated to ipset.  And we've been very happy with it.

However, we recently migrated most of websites to a VPS (OpenVZ) environment and, in the process, discovered that ipset is not (may not be) feasible in that environment.

So ... Are there alternatives to ipset that

- Efficiently handle large sets of ip addresses and ip address ranges (i.e., more efficiently than iptables)
- Can be run in a standard VPS environment.

We run CentOS 6 on our VPS, so alternatives that are available for that distribution would be particularly appealing to us.

Just to be clear ... We are perfectly happy with the manual process we have in place right now for managing the blocked ip addresses / address ranges.  We're not looking for something to automate that process.  Instead, we're concerned primarily with finding a solution similar to ipset that is good about blocking large sets of addresses/ranges without soaking up a huge amount of CPU time.

Comment: Sounds like you should ask a question about whatever problem you're running into with ipset in your new environment. (Personally, the only thing I can think of off the top of my head—and its a lot less flexible—is to use blackhole/null routing + reverse path filter. Of course, that blocks an IP entirely, can't do per-port there. I also haven't tested this, but it'd probably work...)

Comment: After googling, I see that there are problems with ipset, OpenVZ, vmware and kernel versions. As a workaround, have you considered putting a real machine in front of your vps's which can handle ipset (as a firewall), which then forwards onto your vps ?

Comment: @XTian Need not even be a real machine, could be a different kind of VM. And if "putting in front" is a problem: The web servers could use `iptables` to redirect all SYN packets to the other machine which does the filtering.

Comment: @derobert - My understanding from the discussion [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/334885/use-iptables-or-null-route-for-blacklisting-about-1-million-ip-addresses) is that null routing is no more efficient than using iptables.

Comment: @BeSimple wow, that's surprising, as a full Internet routing table is quite a few routes (something like [half a million](http://www.cidr-report.org/as2.0/))... of course, it appears that Serverfault question actually has an answer to your question.

Comment: @XTian - Unfortunately, putting a real machine, or a different kind of VPS, in front of our current VPS isn't an option in our current hosting environment.  Thanks, though, for the suggestion.

Comment: Odd. http://vger.kernel.org/~davem/columbia2012.pdf and http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/quagga/dev/19202 say that FIB lookups on Linux are *not* linear. Maybe it was with the old FIB_HASH implementation? I think only FIB_TRIE is available in modern kernels.

Comment: @derobert - The Serverfault discussion is a good one; I hadn't seen it before posting my question. The solution involving Apache and mod_rewrite is one that I have my reservations about.  However, another potential solution mentioned in the discussion, involving 'libnetfilter_queue`, is one that seems promising.

Comment: This seems to be related and might be the solution: https://serverfault.com/questions/334885/use-iptables-or-null-route-for-blacklisting-about-1-million-ip-addresses/335070#335070